# 95% of my RAM is being used (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, memory

I'm on an HP Envy m7, with 16GB of RAM.

I recently did a clean install of Windows 10 on this computer. But for the past month, i've noticed that when Idle, the system uses way too much RAM.

I have checked for both malware and rootkits (MalwareBytes, Bitdefender, Avast, Kaspersky (for rootkits), and none have been found.

When I checked the processes on Task Manager, the used memory simply doesn't add up.

I then used RamMap to determine it.

[image: RamMap Summary]

[image: Processes Summary]

While RamMap shows that the vast majority of my RAM is being used for Process Private and Page Table, I am still at a loss. When I check the processes tab on RamMap and check the Private Tab, the Usage still doesn't add up to the 15GB being used on my system.

Can anyone help diagnose this issue? Could this be a memory leak in some software? I am running out of options here.

Comment: What good is unused system memory? Your interpretation of what is happening is misguided, unused system memory serves no purpose.  Rest assured, when an application requests the use of your system memory, your system will provide it with that memory.  "Can anyone help diagnose this issue?" - You don't actually have an issue that needs to be solved.

Comment: Is there a performance issue?  Is your computer hanging or something on simple tasks?

Comment: Yes. Chrome is running much slower than usual. I've well aware of the "unused ram is wasted ram" statement, but I've never had it use so much ram at idle, and it is affecting my system performance.

My main concern is why I can't see the processes that accumulated to so much RAM usage.

Comment: I have 3MB "Free" out of 12GB currently.  But my task manager shows under "2GB" used if you add it up (Windows 7)   I doubt your "chrome running slowly" is due to memory  Your CPU seems to be idling above 50% and I am assuming you are running on a HDD (NOT SSD) with 1TB drive and your disk usage shows many spikes to 100%.  I think @Ramhound is correct, it does NOT appear that you have a (RAM) issue that needs solved.  That does not make us right, but by all appearances & your description there seems to be no issues (with RAM usage).

Comment: Okay, thank you. This is the first time I've ever had a computer behave like this, but your explanation makes sense. Thanks again for the answers!

Comment: @SoohanKim - None of the comments submitted is an answer to your question.  They are only comments.

Comment: I have a 12 year old business laptop with old SSD dual core CPU that runs a linux distribution as fast a new budget laptop but with HDD and quad core CPU that is "125%" faster (passmark, not per core). Point is there are alot of variables when it comes to performance.  Good luck!

Comment: @JamesP - So the author should use the various tools to identify the driver, numerous existing questions with answers, that explain that process.  I maintain by my assessment, that snapshot of the memory usage isn't unusual.